# replacing letters in a loop fault

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out why my output is not correct it kinda works but still has some faults in the loop I can't seem to find why. I know there are better ways to do this but i want to learn what went wrong in this loop.

So first it ask a sentence
second question is to replace 2 letters like : a e
third question is to replace it with like : o u

I then split the karakters and put the sentence in an array.
The loop checks every letter in the array and if it comes across one of the letters it should replace it with the one found.

```
var input = prompt("geef een zin ?");
var zin = [];
zin = input.split("");
var inn = prompt("welke karakters wil je veranderen?");
var karaktersinn = inn.split("");
var outt = prompt("in welke letters wil je ze veranderen?");
var karatersout = outt.split("");
var output = "";
console.log(input);


for (var i = 0;i < input.length-1;i++){
   if (zin[i] == karaktersinn[0]){
      output += karatersout[0]

   }if (zin[i] == karaktersinn[2]){
      output += karatersout[2]
   }else{
      output += zin[i];
   }
}

console.log(output);
console.log(zin)
console.log(karaktersinn)
console.log((karatersout))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if conditions are structured like this :

```
if 

if 

else
```

This means you have two if else blocks. So regardless of what happens in the first block, the second block will always be checked, and one of the the last conditions will run

You need an if-else. So at one time only one of the three conditions run.

```js
var input = prompt("geef een zin ?");
var zin = [];
zin = input.split("");
var inn = prompt("welke karakters wil je veranderen?");
var karaktersinn = inn.split("");
var outt = prompt("in welke letters wil je ze veranderen?");
var karatersout = outt.split("");
var output = "";
console.log(input);


for (var i = 0;i < input.length;i++){
   if (zin[i] == karaktersinn[0]){
      output += karatersout[0]

   }else if (zin[i] == karaktersinn[2]){
      output += karatersout[2]
   }else{
      output += zin[i];
   }
}

console.log(output);
console.log(zin)
console.log(karaktersinn)
console.log((karatersout))
```

Also you are running one less iteration of the loop. Fixed that.

Comment: Of course no wonder it didn't work thank you.

Comment: Sure. Please accept/upvote the answer, if it helped you

Comment: i tried but i have not enough reputation to do this sorry.